# Cant see reference node even with Show All Files (VS 2019)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, visual-studio-2019

I needed to add Numerics reference to use system.BigInteger but i cant even if i enable the Show All Files option theres still no Reference folder

Comment: That question is severely lacking in details, but, if you right-click the project node in the Solution Explorer tree, can you find Add->Reference. Remember, there is no "References" folder anywhere, it's just a node in the project tree in the Solution Explorer

Comment: @Flydog57 there is no reference node either

Comment: But, your question still has no information in it. What kind of project is it, is it Framework or Core, how did you create it? Have you tried the obvious (closing and re-opening Visual Studio)? If you repeat your steps (creating a new project, with the same options, at a new location) and get the same results? If you do that, record your steps exactly (for inclusion in your question) . Have you looked inside your SLN and CSPROJ files (the latter is were the references are recorded, look for `<reference/>` elements) . How do they compare with previous projects you've worked with?

Comment: There is no <reference> in my csproj file, how do i add one?

Comment: The normal way would be to right click on the project node in the Solution Explorer, choose Add, then Reference.

Comment: But there is no node even with Show All Files, oh btw when i click "Project" in the toolbar it only says "Export Template", although one time it also said "Add New Item" (both on the csproj file and the cs file)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217223/discussion-between-flydog57-and-octavylon).

Comment: @Flydog57 why arent u answering the chat??

Comment: @Octavylon, I suggest that you can right-click references->Manage Nuget packages-> search 'System.Runtime.Numerics' and install it. Please use the above steps to check if you can use the references successfully.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT thanks that worked (well i didnt have a reference node but i added the nuget package through the Project tool in the toolbar)

Comment: @Octavylon, If my solution works for you, please click '✔' to mark my reply as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you can right-click references->Manage Nuget packages-> search 'System.Runtime.Numerics' and install it.

Please use the above steps to check if you can use the references successfully.